# Run gradle task from condition

Tags: gradle

I am relatively new to gradle so please be patient with me.
My build.gradle:

```
def releaseBol = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    ...
    if (project.hasProperty('RELEASE') && project.ext.RELEASE == '1')
        releaseBol = true


    if (releaseBol)
    {
       ..
       //some code
       ..

    }

}

...

task runScheduleReader()  {
    javaexec {
        println 'here1'
        main="-jar";
        args = [
                "../Generator.jar"

        ]
    }
}
```

What I wish to is to run `runScheduleReader` if `releaseBol` is set to `true`, but I get an error when just moving it there, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
task runScheduleReader()  {
    enabled = releaseBol
    doLast {
       javaexec {
          println 'here1'
          main="-jar";
          args = [
                "../Generator.jar"
          ]
       }
    }
}
```

Please have a look at [enabling and disabling](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N1136C) tasks. The second problem is that you added the logic at *configuration* time so it will be executed every time the script is evaluated. You need to add an action with `doLast`.

Comment: It still running even when releaseBol is false

Comment: @Dim, could you please provide an output of such run?

Comment: Just disabling this task won't help, since it's not of the `JavaExec` type, rather has `javaexec` out of the `doLast` or `doFirst`, which is getting executed at the configuration phase. +1 for the answer anyway

Comment: @Stanislav, when I was out and running I came to the same conclusion ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37990056/4053652), provided by Opal, is right, you can use the `enabled` task option, to skip stask execution. But this is not the only change you have to do.

You're currently made a task without any type and using `javaexec` in tasks closure. That make you `javaexec` running at the build configuration phase and `enabled` property value make no sense. You can make it running at the execution phase this 2 ways: move `javaexec` into the `doLast` closure as:

```
task runScheduleReader()  {
    enabled = releaseBol
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            println 'here1'
            main = "-jar";
            args = [
                    "../Generator.jar"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Or set the task's type and move configuration to it's closure root:

```
task runScheduleReader(type: JavaExec)  {
    enabled = releaseBol

    println 'here1'
    main = "-jar";
    args = [
            "../Generator.jar"
    ]

}
```